# Console output with FileWriter

Tags: java, io, character-encoding, java-io, filewriter

Most probably a *`FileWriter`* is not meant to write to a console, but it does.
So I use it for easy switching between the two destinations.
I only wonder what character conversion takes place when it comes to 8-bit
characters.

Run the following code without any parameter and you will see the difference
between *`System.out.println(...)`* and the *`FileWriter`*'s output.
Run the code giving a file specification as parameter and you will see that the
*`FileWriter`* works as expected.

I tried to:

- translate the test string to *UTF-8*
- passing a character set `(StandardCharsets.UTF_8, Charset.defaultCharset())` to the `FileWriter`
- specifying `FileDescriptor.out` for the `FileWriter`

but to no avail.

Other solutions are ready-at-hand, but still I would like to know whether using a `FileWriter` is possible.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class ConsoleOutput {

  static public void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "Hello äöüß áàâçéèê";
    String filespc = args.length==0 ? "CON:" : args[0];

    boolean console= filespc.equals("CON:"); // For both cmd.exe & PowerShell.
    try (BufferedWriter outfile= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filespc))) {
      
//      if (console) s = new String(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
//                          StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      System.out.println(s);
      outfile.write(s);
      outfile.newLine();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: On macOS terminal, replacing `CON:` with `/dev/stdout`, the code works fine, producing two lines of output that are the same. I think it's an OS/console issue. What unexpected output did your code produce?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for testing. I receive on Windows10 "Hello õ÷³▀ ßÓÔþÚÞÛ"

Comment: Try getting the console encoding with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6173066/5133585). See if it is UTF8. If it is not, try giving that charset to the `FileWriter`. If it is, then I don't know.

Comment: @Sweeper It is the system's default character set (Cp1252), which is also the default for FileWriter. I had already tried to explicitly pass the system's default character set to FileWriter, but there was no change. Thank you anyhow.