# How to find charset of System.err if stdout is redirected?

Tags: java, character-encoding, stdout, stderr, charset

Finding the charset of `System.out` is tricky. (See [Logback System.err output uses wrong encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72419122) for discussion and implications with Logback.) Here's what the `System.out` API documentation says.

> The "standard" output stream. This stream is already open and ready to accept output data. Typically this stream corresponds to display output or another output destination specified by the host environment or user. The encoding used in the conversion from characters to bytes is equivalent to `Console.charset()` if the `Console` exists, `Charset.defaultCharset()` otherwise.

On my Windows 10 Command Prompt using Java 17, `Charset.defaultCharset()` returns `windows-1252`, while `System.console().charset()` returns `IBM437`. If create a `new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, System.console().charset())` and write the string `"é"`, it produces `é` as expected. But if I use `new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, Charset.defaultCharset())` and write `"é"`, it produces `Θ`! That's why it is imperative that I use `new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, System.console().charset())`.

There's a wrinkle: as [Baeldung explains](https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-console-vs-system-out), if `stdout` is being redirected (e.g. `… > temp.out` on the command line), then `System.console()` will be `null` and `Charset.defaultCharset()` should be used instead. Thus we can determine the charset used for `System.out` like this (which isn't the most efficient code, but it illustrates the point):

```
final Charset systemOutCharset = System.console() != null
    ? System.console().charset() : Charset.defaultCharset();
```

But here is the huge problem: `System.err` supposedly plays by the same rules: if there is a `Console`, then `System.console().charset()` is used as the `System.err` charset, otherwise `Charset.defaultCharset()`.

> The encoding used in the conversion from characters to bytes is equivalent to `Console.charset()` if the `Console` exists, `Charset.defaultCharset()` otherwise.

As we saw, if we redirect `stdout`, then there is no `Console`. What if we redirect `stdout` but not `stderr`? On my system, `System.out` will be writing (redirected) using the charset `windows-1252`, and `System.err` will still be printing to the console using the charset `IBM437`. This seems to directly contradict its API contract, as in the absence of `Console` `System.err` is using, not `Charset.defaultCharset()`, but instead some other charset (what `Console.charset()` would have returned if it were present). Moreover there's no longer any way to access the charset of `System.err`, because there is no `System.console()` because `stdout` is being redirected!

**How can I discover the correct charset to use for `System.err` if `stdout` is being redirected?** And why isn't `System.err` adhering to its API contract in this scenario?

I can only assume this was an oversight of the Java API and there should be a `System.getConsoleCharset()` method which would return the correct value whether or not `System.console()` is present.

This has larger implications than you might think. A logging system such as Logback (see [LOGBACK-1642](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1642)) is typically configured to send log output to `stderr` (see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331611), and logging packages are not going to require Java 18 (mentioned in an answer below) for years and years to come, as they implement cross-cutting functionality that must work with the lowest supported Java versions. Because of this Java bug (and it does seem to be a bug coupled with an API blind spot), *there is no way for a logging system to know for certain which charset to use for its output* if using `stderr` which is arguably best practice!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172972/how-to-get-console-charset Or make it a configuration option till java 18. Or use ProcessBuilder with a Windows command.

Answer (score 2):

Java 18 has [exactly what you need](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#charset%28%29):

> ## Class PrintStream
>
> [...]
>
> ---
>
> `public Charset charset()`
> Returns the charset used in this PrintStream instance.
>
> **Returns:**
> the charset used in this PrintStream instance
> **Since:**
> 18

Unfortunately, this means that there are only hacks out there for earlier Java versions - as such methods are usually only added because it is needed.

With that, the charset to use is simply

```
System.err.charset()
```

---

If you need to support earlier Java versions, you can use code like this:

```
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodType.methodType;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public final class PrintStreamCharset {
    
    private PrintStreamCharset() {}
    
    private static final MethodHandle PS_CHARSET;
    
    public static Charset charset(PrintStream ps) {
        try {
            return (Charset) PS_CHARSET.invokeExact(ps);
        } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(t);
        }
    }
    
    static {
        MethodHandle mh;
        Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
        try {
            try {
                mh = l.findVirtual(PrintStream.class, "charset", methodType(Charset.class));
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
                mh = makeMHPreJava18(l);
            }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
        PS_CHARSET = mh;
    }
    
    private static MethodHandle makeMHPreJava18(Lookup l) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Lookup pl = privateLookup(l);
        try {
            MethodHandle getOSW = pl.findGetter(PrintStream.class, "charOut",
                    OutputStreamWriter.class);
            MethodHandle getEncodingName = l.findVirtual(OutputStreamWriter.class, "getEncoding",
                    methodType(String.class));
            MethodHandle findCharset = l.findStatic(Charset.class, "forName",
                    methodType(Charset.class, String.class));
            return MethodHandles.filterReturnValue(
                    MethodHandles.filterReturnValue(getOSW, getEncodingName), findCharset);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
    
    private static Lookup privateLookup(Lookup origin) throws IllegalAccessException {
        try {
            return (Lookup) MethodHandles.class
                    .getMethod("privateLookupIn", Class.class, Lookup.class)
                    .invoke(null, PrintStream.class, origin);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof Error) {
                throw (Error) cause;
            } else if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) cause;
            } else if (cause instanceof IllegalAccessException) {
                throw (IllegalAccessException) cause;
            } else {
                throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(cause);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            // Java 8 - get MethodHandles.Lookup.IMPL_LOOKUP
            Field implLookupField;
            try {
                implLookupField = Lookup.class.getDeclaredField("IMPL_LOOKUP");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
                nsme.addSuppressed(nsfe);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(nsme);
            }
            implLookupField.setAccessible(true);
            Lookup implLookup = (Lookup) implLookupField.get(null);
            return implLookup.in(PrintStream.class);
        }
    }
}
```

This requires you to pass `--add-opens java.base/java.io=<YOUR-MODULE-NAME>` on the command line for Java 9 to Java 17.

With Java 18+ this will simply call `PrintStream.charset()`.
With earlier Java versions, it will do some equivalent to `Charset.forName(ps.charOut.getEncoding())`.

I did test this with Java 8, Java 11, Java 17 and Java 18.
Considering that it uses an official API with Java 18 and Java 8 - Java 17 are only getting updates, this is somewhat unlikely to break in the future.

Comment: Well, that's nice to know. Too bad it won't be an a LTS until late next year. What can I use for my other projects still using Java 11? Or my libraries using Java 8 to appeal to a wider audience?

Comment: `Console.charset()` was added in Java 17. Before that? Hack into the `PrintStream.charset` field.

Comment: If the charset hasn't been changed, it will be the [same as this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset())

Comment: Johannes, I hadn't realized `Console.charset()` was only added recently. So how do you propose to "hack into the `PrintStream.charset` field"? Through some reflection magic (which would surely break with modularization)?

Comment: Yes, reflection. Won't break for Java 8-17 (very unlikely that the field will change in those releases now), and then add `--add-opens java.base/java.io=<YOUR-MODULE-NAME>` to the command line.